# Where are functions stored in memory?

Tags: c, function

Where are functions stored in memory in c?
Can anyone explain it in simply language?

```
#include stdio.h>

void g()
{
    int a=7;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(g()));
    printf("%p",&g);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the following program is

```
1
00007ff6ee001581
```

and where the variable inside the function is stored and linked with function address

Comment: `sizeof(g())` is nonsense - it is invalid C.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Please take some time to check your posted code for obvious typographical errors: what do you expect the preprocessor to do with `stdio.h>`? And what would you expect the size of a `void` to be?

Comment: The language does not specify where functions are stored. They might not even be in traditional memory at all! (E.g., Harvard architecture.) (Printing a function pointer with `%p` is UB by the way.)

Comment: `sizeof(g())` is the size of the return type, i.e. `sizeof(void)`. It's not supposed to compile, `void` has no size.

Comment: @Lundin the output 1

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OP is probably using gcc in non-standards-compliant mode, in which case [`sizeof(void)==1`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith).

Comment: Clang seems to think that a `void` takes up 1 byte. MSVC, on the other hand, says it has no size at all (zero bytes).

Comment: it is <stdio.h>

Comment: Typically, code is loaded in an area of memory called the text segment, variables reside in the data segment.

Comment: @stark (Function) local variables are frequently stored on the stack.

Comment: @rosterrz There is no output on a standard C compiler since it doesn't compile. You are relying on some gcc extension treating void as char. Please check [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) and then configure your compiler to become a standard C language one.

Comment: Anyway, a general computer stores all executable code inside a segment often called `.text` and that's about it. This segment has nothing to do with where variables are stored.

Comment: What sort of answer do you want? There is a bunch of memory, or at least a bunch of address space that we can map to physical memory. We need some space for data for variables that exist through the lifetime of the program, some for stack space, some for the instructions of the program, and some for memory that is allocated during program execution. So we carve up the address space, designating some area for the stack, some for data, some for instructions, and so on. You printed the address of the function, so you see its address. There is your answer. What else do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output of the following program is

The second line of output is a pointer to the code for the function `g`. It's the address of that function, and it's the literal the answer to your question about where the function is stored.

> and where the variable inside the function is stored and linked with function address

The variable `a` is a local variable, so it only exists while the function is executing. Usually the compiler will create space for local variables on the stack -- that's one of the main reasons for having a stack. Once the function returns, its local variables are popped off the stack and they cease to exist. In other words, `a` isn't connected to the location of `g` at all.

Local variables are typically referenced via some offset from the stack pointer. When you call a function, a *stack frame* is created on the stack. The stack frame basically consists of storage for all the function's local variables, and also the address of the previous stack pointer and the return address. The function's code then starts executing, and since the compiler knows the *relative* address of each variable (i.e. where it is in the stack frame), it can easily calculate the absolute address. Most processors have instructions that make relative addressing easy for exactly this reason. When the function exits, the stack pointer is set back to the previous stack frame and the processor jumps to the return address. But this is just one possible implementation; on modern processors that have lots of registers, local variables may not even be stored on the stack -- they may just end up in registers.

Answer (score 3):

The variable inside function are stored in stack.

And every linking and addressing part is done by linker.

In simple words linker decides what absolute address to give to what label or function and compiler decides how they will be arranged and will be able to address each other.

Compiling takes four steps:

```
  Preprocessing [in which header file and microprocessor worked upon].

  Compiling[In which they are converted into assembly code]

  Assembly[In which codes are converted into machine level language but have relative addressing in respect to there starting]

  Linking[When absolute address is given so when loaded they can address each other and files and linked in one]
```

#I think these last lines can help you

Functions and variable are labels and every label is translated into address. The code that runs on machine have address that represent these labels. And not only c but every compiled language goes through it. As on machine its machine code or just wiring.

Say if you not understood anything. Will be glad to help you

Comment: if function address is 0x077, then if there is variable inside the have have next consecutive address or somewhere else, if  it is somewhere else how they link for example if i call function to print variable inside it

Answer (score 1):

```
include <stdio.h>

void g()
{
int a=7;
}

int main()
{
//printf("%d\n",sizeof(g()));
//you cant use sizeof(g()) its a functiona and
//function not have anysize

printf("%p",&g);
//even you can't use here int a=7 that you declared in void g() as it is local to
//that function and this function cant access any function local variable
//but what it returns

return 0;
}
```

If you want to see addressing than see this:

```
0000000000001135 <g>:
1135:   55                      push   %rbp
1136:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
1139:   c7 45 fc 07 00 00 00    movl   $0x7,-0x4(%rbp)
1140:   90                      nop
1141:   5d                      pop    %rbp
1142:   c3                      retq   

0000000000001143 <main>:
1143:   55                      push   %rbp
1144:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
1147:   48 8d 35 e7 ff ff ff    lea    -0x19(%rip),%rsi        # 1135 <g>
114e:   48 8d 3d af 0e 00 00    lea    0xeaf(%rip),%rdi        # 2004       
<_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
1155:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
115a:   e8 d1 fe ff ff          callq  1030 <printf@plt>
115f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
1164:   5d                      pop    %rbp
1165:   c3                      retq   
1166:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
116d:   00 00 00
```